# How to make all dataTable columns inputs readOnly

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

i have a `<p:datable>` with `<p:column>` , inside each column i have a `<p:inputTex>`..
i'm wondering if there is  a way to make all these `<p:inputTex>` readOnly without doing that manually (readOnly="true" for each `<p:inputTex>`) because i have a lot of columns..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OnmiFaces massAttribute](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute) is designed specifically for this.

From their showcase (slightly adapted for this case):

```
<o:massAttribute name="readonly" value="#{formBean.shouldBeReadonly}" target="javax.faces.component.UIInput">
    <h:outputLabel for="input1" />
    <h:inputText id="input1" />
    <h:outputLabel for="input2" />
    <h:inputText id="input2" />
    <h:outputLabel for="input3" />
    <h:inputText id="input3" />
</o:massAttribute>
```

The `target` attribute is to make sure only input components are, well... targeted and not the outputs or other components. You can also use a static `value` of 'true' instead of referencing a getter in a bean.

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje , i got it , do you have any  idea on how to apply this <o:massAttribute> on my <p:datatable>

Comment: Try wrap it around the `p:datatable`... I'd think it works recursively...